# Do I have to maintain my hijab to my half-sisters?

Tags: hijab

I've two half-sisters, ie. same father different mother.

Do I have to maintain the hijab, lower my gaze to them like they weren't from my family?

I don't have any haram attraction towards them, I see them as real sisters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between full sisters and half-sisters in this regard, they are your eternal mahrams by blood relationship. It is permissible to look at such a woman in the absence of desire. Also she is not required to observe hijab from you.

Answer (score 0):

Do I have to keep my hijab for my half-sisters?
Your sisters are also Muharrams to you. A woman does not have to observe the hijab in the face of an incestuous husband, like her father-in-law or her own brother, but it is against caution to wear clothes that arouse lust.

Ref: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa4325

Answer (score -3):

Asalamu alykom wa rahmut allah wa baraktuh (peace be upon muslims) and asalatu wa salamu aala sayedna wa habeebna wa qudwatuna Muhammad ibnu abdullah ama baaad,

Dear sister, it is mandatory by Allah's command for you to wear the hijab to avoid the attraction of wrong doirs wa al eeyaathu bellah.

I suggest you to always be careful especially with the closest one to your heart as they may have zina intentions astaghfirullah.